# Why can't I assign and then check a variable in the same if statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In other words, why doesn't this show an alert?

```
var x;
if (x = 1 && x > 0) {
    alert(x);
}
```

As far as I understand, x = 1 should assign 1 to x and also return 1.  The x > 0 check is failing. Why?

Comment: `x == 1` I think

Comment: In addition to the answers below, also *just don't do that*. It's ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the `&&` operation will have precedence over the assignment.

In you case, `x` will be the result of `1 && x > 0` which is `false`.

```js
var x;
if (x = 1 && x > 0) {
  alert(x);
}
console.log(x); // false
```

You can enforce the order of operations using parentheses, [as shown by Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655910/3928341).

Answer (score 2):

You need some parens to separate the assignment from the ongoing expression.

```js
var x;
if ((x = 1) && x > 0) {
    alert(x);
}
```